# wireless woes Ubuntu won't hook up to my built in hardware gateway laptop

Tags: wireless

I installed ubuntu on my lap top that runs winxp, I really like ubuntu and will probably get rid of windows all together, but ubuntu won't access my built in wirless or wi-fi.  In windows i use broadcom.   any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you described your hardware, Ubuntu version, showed us the output of `sudo lshw -short | grep -i network`, it would help us help you. On my laptop (Dell Latitude D630) I get:

```
sudo lshw -short|grep -i network
[sudo] password for walt: 
/0/100/1c.1/0                    network     BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
/0/100/1c.5/0        eth0        network     NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
```

and I can easily find out that for the BCM4311 chip I need the b43 driver, and how to access it. (`sudo modprobe b43` in my case, for testing, `echo "b43" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules` to make it permanent). This works for me, YMMV.